# Question about matrix and diagonals

Tags: matrices

I have to write a program in C++ to determinate the following:

1. Sum of main diagonal
2. Sum of elements above main diagonal
3. Sum of elements below main diagonal
4. Sum of secondary diagonal
5. Sum of elements above secondary diagonal
6. Sum of elements below secondary diagonal

So, I wanna firstly see how does it solve in math.

I know the following:

1. It has to equal `i == j` to be true. That is easy.
2. If `i < j`
3. If `i > j`.
4. Not sure
5. Not sure
6. Not sure

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Wrote out a 2x2, then 3x3, the 4x4 using $a_{11}, a_{12} ... a_{nn}$ and see if you can figure out the pattern.

Comment: @Amzoti I did, but it's kinda hard... i'm still trying to see.

Comment: I guess your attempt for the solution assumes that you have a loop over all row and columns (that is, $n^2$ loop iterations). It is, IMHO, a very bad solution if $n$ is somewhat large.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel In my case it's not large, but I don't know any better way either, I'm a very beginner... also, one question off-question, how do you calculate the complexly of a problem? Like whether it's n, logn or n^2?

Comment: 1 and 4 should be implemented using one loop, they have $O(n)$ complexity and $O(n^2)$ for the rest (hint: how many elements you have to sum in the given $n\times n$ matrix to get the result?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $i$ is the "row" and the $j$ is the "column", and assuming that the input is a square matrix...

1. `i == j`
2. `i < j`
3. `i > j`
4. `i+j == n-1` (where $n$ is the number of rows/columns of the matrix)
5. `i+j < n-1`
6. `i+j > n-1`

Try to prove on your own that these are the answers!

Comment: btw, I'm assuming that the matrix is a standard double array in C++, with indices starting at $0$ instead of $1$. If the indices are $1$ to $n$ instead of $0$ to $n-1$, change all $n-1$s into $n+1$.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure about the 4th one??

Comment: Ok, I get it, about the n-1 and n+1 part, and as for the 4th one I think it's good as you said, except in programming way it's n - j - 1. (where j is the column)

Comment: `i == n-j-1` and `i+j == n-1` are equivalent expressions, so as long as you use the one that fits your purpose better, it should be the same. I just chose the `i+j` because it looks nicer.

Comment: Wow.. well, you're right. I just learned something new here! Thanks for that.  I appreciate your help and time! Merry Christmas.

Comment: @user117293 I hope you're not using two loops for 1 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

I will let you do the declarations etc and give you the core functionality.

Assuming A is $N\times N$ and you use standard zero indexing

for (i=0; i $<$ N; i++) diagsum += A[i][i];

for (i=0; i $<$N; i++) secondarydiagsum += A[i][N-i-1];

for (i=0; i $<$ N; i++) for (j=i+1;j$<$N;j++) abovesum += A[i][j]; //i is row, j is column

for (i=0; i $<$N; i++) for (j=0;j$<$i;j++) belowsum += A[i][j]; //i is row, j is column

for (i=0; i $<$N; i++) for (j=0;j$<$ N-i-1;j++) abovesecondarysum += A[i][j];

for (i=0; i $<$N; i++) for (j=N-i;j$<$ N;j++) belowsecondarysum += A[i][j];

Please check the limits. I am having a hard time formatting C++ code here